# Three.js Points, BufferGeometry : rendering point as circle

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, shader

I'm new to three.js and shaders at all.
I need to create a sphere of particles, which move on surface like waves, but that's not a problem. Right now I got something like this.
[image: current result]

And here is result I need.
[image: target result]

So, how to render each point as circle or maybe, render texture? Right now my fragment shader is

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform vec2 repeat;
uniform float uTime;

varying vec2 vOffset;

precision mediump float;

varying vec3 vColor;
varying vec2 vUv;
void main()
{
        vec2 uv = vec2( gl_PointCoord.x, 1.0 - gl_PointCoord.y );

        vec4 tex = texture2D( texture, uv * 0.5);

        gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(0.5, 0.8, 0.85), 0.8);
}
```

Ofc i tried to render gl_FragColor = tex, but it doesn't seem to work though. My texture is just a particle.

[image: particle]

Comment: Have a look at this [article](https://www.desultoryquest.com/blog/drawing-anti-aliased-circular-points-using-opengl-slash-webgl/).

Comment: That's great and works. Can you advise something to render it not as circle, but as texture now?

Comment: It's better to ask another question with better clarification about "as a texture". :) I dare to assume that you mean something like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49895821/4045502). If not, then ask another question.

Comment: I actually can render texture, but it renders completely transparent, idk why.

Comment: That's why it's better to provide a live code example :)

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean `gl_FragColor = tex` didn't work?

If you want to use a texture the code should be

```
uniform sampler2D texture;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, gl_PointCoord);
}
```

and you should probably turn on blending and set it up for premultiplied alpha and make sure your texture is using premultiplied alpha and the depth test is off.